# Unable to import modules in haskell

Tags: haskell, import

I'm really new to haskell, and I'm having a problem importing any modules whatsoever.

When I load an .hs file that contains nothing but

```
import Data.list
```

it gives me an error of

```
file.hs:1:8: parse error on input Data.list
```

I know I must be making a really basic error somewhere, because imports seem to be working for everyone else, even in all the tutorials. Is it because I've changed my directory with :cd? Or is it how my GHCi was downloaded?

Comment: These are perfect questions for #haskell on IRC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modules start with capital letters

```
 import Data.List
```

Answer (score 3):

Module names are capitalized.

Capitalize the word "List".

```
import Data.List
```