# Importing Modules in Haskell (beginner)

Tags: haskell, module

I've just begun learning Haskell today and have been alternating between video lectures, programming exercises and the http://learnyouahaskell.com/ e-Book. One thing that I haven't come across yet in my learning is the best-practice way for importing custom modules, and I guess in general *how* Haskell imports modules.

### Context

For the past few hours, I had been creating projects using the command line `stack new [ProjectName]` and modifying the `Lib.hs` file in the `src` subdirectory (see image). This is how I would test the functionality of my scripts. This was until I discovered that within the `app` subdirectory there was a `Main.hs` file calling the `Lib.hs` module. So instead I tried to create my own `.hs` file in the `src` subdir for that to get called instead of the default `Lib.hs`.

[image: Project Directory Structure]

My main, after modification looks like

```
module Main (main) where

import Lib
import SpaceAge -- my attempt to import custom module

main :: IO ()
main = ageOn  -- Previously someFunc from Lib.hs
```

where the custom module `SpaceAge.hs` which rests in the `src` subdir looks like this.

```
-- This script is from one of the programming exercises
import SpaceAge ( Planet(..), ageOn ) where

data Planet = Mercury
    | Venus
    | Earth
    | Mars
    | Jupiter
    | Saturn
    | Uranus
    | Neptune

ageOn :: Planet -> Float -> Float
ageOn planet seconds = seconds / earthYear * planetMultiplier
    where
        planetMultiplier = case planet of
            Mercury -> 0.2408467
            Venus ->   0.61519726
            Earth ->   1
            Mars ->    1.8808158
            Jupiter -> 11.862615
            Saturn ->  29.447498
            Uranus ->  84.016846
            Neptune -> 164.79132
        earthYear = 31557600
```

Running this project in VS Code yields the error: `parse error on input 'where'` on on Line 1 after the module is interpreted. I've been toiling for about an hour now troubleshooting and googling to no avail. I found in the eBook that custom modules should be in the same directory as the `Main.hs` file. I tried this but get the error `can't find file: .\Ex2\src\SpaceAge.hs`.

Can somebody tell me if my error lies in one of these things?

1. `SpaceAge.hs` needs to be in the same directory as `Main.hs`? If so, why does this reference issue not affect the default `Lib.hs`?
2. The `SpaceAge.hs` file contains errors?
3. Need to modify `package.yaml`?
4. Type error on `Main.main`?

If more detail to the question is needed - I will edit the question accordingly. Thank you.

---

I have read the following similar questions:

1. [Unable to import modules in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273190/unable-to-import-modules-in-haskell) (not the same error message)
2. [Importing Crypto Modules in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003392/importing-crypto-modules-in-haskell) (does not seem pertinent to my issue)

Comment: This should be `module SpaceAge (..) where`,  Not `import SpageAge where` in `SpageAge.hs`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue. Can you make this an answer so that I may close this question?

Comment: I think just delete it since that's just a typo and unlikely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple typo. Where you write

```
import SpaceAge ( Planet(..), ageOn ) where
```

you should write

```
module SpaceAge ( Planet(..), ageOn ) where
```

The `import` statement is for importing names from a different module; You need the `module` statement to declare a module name (and export list).